# Typescript: Type of a function that takes a function argument - getting "; expected" error

Tags: typescript

I've got a class that has a property which is a function type, which takes a function as an argument.  The typescript compiler is producing a "; expected" error on the second `=>`.  Any thoughts why?  Code is below.

```
class Foo{
    public fn: ((string) => void) => void;
}

var foo = new Foo();
foo.fn = function(logger: (string) => void): void{
    logger("bar");
};

var writeToConsole = function(str: string): void {
    console.log(str);
}

foo.fn(writeToConsole);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the inner function needs a name and only then you can specify it's type:

```
public fn: (inner: (string) => void) => void;
```

Obviously the `inner` is arbitrary, change it to your liking. See it working at [Typescript playground](http://goo.gl/wz9PGn) (note: using shortened url because the original link includes parentheses which mess up markdown and I don't fancy escaping all of them)